# how can I generate the list of elements of list with duplicated elements

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

for example if I have a list like this :

```
list =['a','a','a','b','b','b','c']
```

I want to know how many different elements are in my list and generate a list like this:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
```

Comment: Did any of the solutions work for you if so please mark one as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set(list)
```

produces

```
>>> set(list)
{'b', 'a', 'c'}
```

If you then want it as a list you can use

```
list(set(list))
```

Comment: he needs a list, hence `list(set(a))`

Answer (score 1):

```
full_list = ["a", "b", "a", "c", "c"]
list_without_duplicaion = list(dict.fromkeys(full_list))
print(list_without_duplicaion)
```

Try out this answer and let me know is working as your expectations.

https://repl.it/@TamilselvanLaks/arrwithoutdup